# How to change Webrtc rtcpMuxPolicy?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, rtcp, rtcpeerconnection

I am trying to change `rtcpMuxPolicy` and also the `bundlePolicy`, but it seems like it cannot be changed

This is my code:

*Attempt 1:*

```
var servers = {
    'iceServers': [{
        'urls': 'stun-url..'
    }, {
        'urls': 'stun-url-2..'
    }, {
        'urls': 'turn-url..',
        'credential': 'psw',
        'username': 'user'
    }],
    peerIdentity: [{bundlePolicy: 'max-bundle', rtcpMuxPolicy: 'negotiate'}]//added this line
};

var pc;
var sendChannel;

navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia);

pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
```

*Attempt 2:*

```
var servers = {
        'iceServers': [{
            'urls': 'stun-url..'
        }, {
            'urls': 'stun-url-2..'
        }, {
            'urls': 'turn-url..',
            'credential': 'psw',
            'username': 'user'
        }]
    };

    var pc;
    var sendChannel;

    navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia);

    pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
    pc.setConfiguration([{bundlePolicy: 'max-bundle', rtcpMuxPolicy: 'negotiate'}]);
```

With both examples, I am still seeing the default values:

```
pc.getConfiguration()

bundlePolicy: "balanced"
rtcpMuxPolicy: "require"
```

And I can notice only one change and that is, the `iceServers` array is empty, but 
`bundlePolicy`, and `rtcpMuxPolicy` are still the default.

I have WebRtc web solution that communicates with an Android application and everything works perfectly when streaming video, the problem occurs when I add dataChannel i.e.

```
sendChannel = pc.createDataChannel('sendDataChannel');
```

After adding the above line in my web solution, the android throws an error saying:

> setSDP error:  Failed to set remote offer sdp:  Session error code:
>   ERROR_CONTENT.  Session error description: Failed to setup RTCP mux
>   filter..

Comment: Remove `peerIdentity: [{` and `}]`. Only `iceServers` expects an array.

Answer (score 1):

First off, remove `peerIdentity: [{` and `}]`. Only `iceServers` expects an array. The syntax is:

```js
const pc = new RTCPeerConnection({
  iceServers: [{urls: 'stun-url..'}, {urls: 'stun-url-2..'}],
  bundlePolicy: 'max-bundle', // add this line
  rtcpMuxPolicy: 'negotiate'  // and this one
});
```

```
pc.setConfiguration({bundlePolicy: 'max-bundle', rtcpMuxPolicy: 'negotiate'});
```

Secondly, note that even though [some browsers](https://wpt.fyi/results/webrtc/RTCConfiguration-rtcpMuxPolicy.html?label=experimental&label=master&aligned) support `rtcpMuxPolicy`, the feature the `'negotiate'` value controls is marked *"Feature at risk"* in the [specification](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-rtcrtcpmuxpolicy), so setting this value is most likely not supported.

The spec says: *"the user agent MAY not implement non-multiplexed RTCP, in which case it will reject attempts to construct an RTCPeerConnection with the negotiate policy."*